# Ionic platform ready event fires twice

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Does anyone know how to prevent the event from firing twice? I've tried using a controller scope level boolean variable to see if the event has already fired, but it did not work. It is like the event is firing on 2 separate threads and the variable was always false.

In the code below the $ionicPlatform.ready event is firing twice, but I can't figure out why.I'm using the current version of the Ionic Framework ionic-v1.0.0-beta.13.

```
angular.module('rsgApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$ionicPlatform', 
function ($ionicPlatform) {  
    var vm = this;

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        alert('device is ready');
    });

 }]);
```

Comment: This may happen because your controller is being loaded twice. Crosscheck your html and routes configurations to make sure that you have one and only declaration of controller for a particular HTML file.

Comment: I thought the controller was getting loaded twice also, but I can't find out where. I only see that the controller is only being loaded once, but the event fire twice

Comment: Please share your routes and corresponding html, preferably in a plunker..

Answer (score 4):

Thanks TechMa9iac I was able to resolve this problem. In my tab template I had added an 'ng-controller' attribute to my ion-content tag. This is what was causing the $ionicPlatform.ready event to fire twice.